# How can I check what key comparer an IReadOnlyDictionary is using?

Tags: c#, dictionary, case-insensitive

I have a `Dictionary<string, T>` that I want to use in a method. The method does not need to modify the Dictionary, so I want to pass it in as an `IReadOnlyDictionary<string, T>`. I want to check that the Dictionary's key comparer is case-insensitive. If it were a `Dictionary<string, T>` then I could:

```
Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(abbreviations.Comparer == StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
```

But it appears that IReadOnlyDictionary does not have a Comparer property. What can I substitute for the above assert?

Comment: `IReadOnlyDictionary` does not expose a `Comparer`, because it only makes sense when you are `Add`ing elements to a dictionary. You can simply pass your own interface which additionally has a Comparer

Comment: You claim that a Comparer is only relevant when you are adding elements. I don't have any idea why you think this is the case. You are obviously wrong. I have, in the question, provided a use case for wanting to know what the Comparer is that has nothing to do with adding elements. Specifically, I want to assert that the Comparer is case-insensitive. I want to do this because I want to make sure that I don't have to care about the case of the string keys when I try to fetch elements from the Dictionary, or check whether elements exist in the Dictionary.

Comment: Then you OBVIOUSLY do not want to USE IReadOnlyDictionary because IT is not meant for this kind of thing

Comment: I want a Dictionary that is read-only. If IReadOnlyDictionary is "not meant for this kind of thing", then it is at minimum poorly-named, and I would disagree that its "not being meant for this kind of thing" is "obvious", since having to look past the name of the interface is in my view sufficient to establish non-obviousness.

Comment: Come on man I did not name the interface, if you really have a problem with the naming, as you know .Net is open source now you can just ask for it ;) However, it does not change the fact that `IReadOnlyDictionary` is not meant for this kind of thing whether you want it or not. Just by simply looking at the interface you can see what it is meant for ;) `Keys`,`Values`,`ContainsKey`,`TryGetValue` any other usage you want to do is clearly, obviously not meant for `IReadOnlyDictionary`. 
If you want a Dictionary that is read-only and has comparer then you have to implement it yourself.

Comment: I did not intend to disparage or harangue you. But still, I don't think that wanting to know about the Comparer used by a Dictionary is incompatible with it being read-only, and I don't think there's a good reason it was left off the interface.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you can do by defining your own interface :) I hope it helps

```
public interface IMyReadOnlyInterface<TKey, TValue> : IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue> {
IEqualityComparer<TKey> Comparer { get; }
}

public class MyReadOnlyDict<TKey, TValue> : Dictionary<TKey, TValue>, IMyReadOnlyInterface<TKey, TValue> {
}

public void TestMethod(IMyReadOnlyInterface<string, object> dict){
    var compareMe = dict.Comparer;
    //DO STUFF
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Comparer<TKey> Comparer` property does not implement an interface.

A pragmatic approach would be to try and cast the parameter to `(ReadOnly)Dictionary<string, T>`, but then you'd be kind of breaking the promise you make in the API/interface/method signature.

An alternative, making the signature more complex and error-prone, would be to require both the dictionary and its comparer to be passed as a parameter. But that would allow the caller to pass any comparer, not necessarily the one applied to the dictionary.

As [suggested in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43833749/how-can-i-check-what-key-comparer-an-ireadonlydictionary-is-using#comment74704346_43833749) by Emrah, you could introduce an interface:

```
public interface IComparableReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue>
    : IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue>
{
    IEqualityComparer<TKey> Comparer { get; }
}
```

And introduce your own dictionary type inheriting from that:

```
public class ComparableReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue>
: ComparableReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue>,
  IComparableReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue>
{   
}
```

That doesn't allow for a friendly public API though.

You could also just settle on using the type `Dictionary<string, T>` as parameter type.